# SwiftUI - Error when presenting messageComposeViewController from MessageUI on presented sheet

Tags: swift

In my SwiftUI project, I am getting the error message "Warning: attempt to present MFMessageComposeViewController on ....HostingController...ContentView which is already presenting (my sheet)" Basically, it's not letting me present the message view controller because I already have a sheet presented.

Is there any way to present the message view controller on top of the sheet? If not, how can I dismiss the sheet before the display of the message view controller if I want it all to happen with one button click? I have already tried ways of dismissing sheets (using environmental variable or passing binding bool variable) but always get the error (No!)ForcedTimeOut or something like that. Thanks